# sed command in UNIX for XML parsing

Tags: unix, sed

i have to replace the simple xml tag

```
<connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
```

by

```
<connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http"
     socket-binding="http"
     enabled="false"/>
```

how i can achieve this using sed command

i tried to replace by simple sed command as i am beginner using

```
sed 's/connector name="http" protocol="HTTP\/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/connector name="http" protocol="HTTP\/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" enable="false"' abcd.xml`
```

but i am getting message

```
command garbled: s/connector name="http" protocol="HTTP\/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/connector name="http" protocol="HTTP\/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" enable="false"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `s/old/new/` command is missing the final slash.  Try:

```
sed 's/connector name="http" protocol="HTTP\/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/connector name="http" protocol="HTTP\/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" enable="false"/' abcd.xml
```